# Redirect from mxml to another mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am very new to Flex & Action script and here is my requirement:

if user click on Login button (on login.mxml) it redirects to success.mxml page which is already implemented in my project. As per new requirement, if login failed due to password expired, I need to redirect to some other mxml (changepassword.mxml) page.

Please let me know, how to redirect the from mxml to another mxml page based on condition (success/failure)

Comment: Tell me the container where you have all these pages ?

Comment: Currently i am using Jetty as Appserver and all these page are in Web project.

Comment: By Container I meant the flex container like ViewStack etc , We cannot help until you ell us the flex application structure like where are these pages ? All these pages must be part of a single flex app , i guess !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ViewStack component to achieve this. onLoad of your application set the viewStack selectedIndex = 0; if login success then change to selectedIndex = 1; else if failure then change to selectedIndex = 2; Like this is your tags. (Login is your main login form mxml. and LoginSuccess and LoginFailure are another mxml files)

`<mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack" selectedIndex="0" historyManagementEnabled="false">
                        <login:Login id="loginMxml" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" >
            </login:Login>
            <login:LoginSuccess id="loginSuccess"> 
            </login:LoginSuccess>
            <login:LoginFailure id="loginFailure"/>
            </login:LoginFailure>
</mx:ViewStack>`

in action script

`if(login == "success"){
                myViewStack.selectedIndex = 1;
            }else if(login == "failure"){
                myViewStack.selectedIndex = 2;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Click the following link and chack how to redirect from one mxml to another mxml

http://bkissuesolver.blogspot.in/2013/05/redirect-from-one-mxml-to-another-mxml.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include an actual answer into your post, instead of mere link. Thanks.